# iOS7 UIPickerView - touches go through to subview in background

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I have a UIPicker view that is in front of a UITableView.

The issue I am having is that touches appear to be going through the UIPickerView and handled by another subview (UITableView) that is behind the picker.

When I touch the picker view and drag in some places it is causing the tableview behind the UIPicker view to scroll as well.

Am I missing something simple here? Or is this a new issue in iOS 7?

[Video showing the behavior](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6p57Sg_9QOc&feature=youtu.be)

Example Project: https://github.com/mrkd/iOS7pickerViewTests

UPDATE - This was a bug and was fixed with the iOS 7.1 release.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20997158/1405008 check here for my solution already posted to same kind of question.

Answer (score 2):

i can't understand why, but if you add a view below the pickerView, the problem will be resolved

Comment: Yes - this is the work around I ended up using. I filed a radar as well.

Comment: FYI - this was fixed in iOS 7.1

Comment: Including an image of such a thing may be useful, though I suppose it's a little late for that. 