# Uipickerview behind item working

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

I have `pickerview` in my view controller. I am displaying it by adding into subview and then changing frame of subview. When my `pickerview` displayed I have one button behind it. When I click on those area after dispalying `pickerview` still that button action is called. How to set `pickerview` proper?

Comment: did you use ActionSheet?

Comment: Can you please explain your question? What do you mean by "setting up proper". The action of the button which is behind the pickerview probably triggers because of a bug in pickerview. First of all you can report this after that you can easily hide of disable user interaction on the button while presenting the pickerview.

Comment: I hope this is working in ios7. So its apple functionality. You can do it according to your logic. I mean you can disable the user interaction of view when pickerview is shown and if the pickerview is hidden then make the view's interaction is enable.

Comment: check my answer for fix

Answer (score 1):

U subclass the PickerView like below will help u to fix this issue.

```
//
//  WPCustomPickerView.h
//  test
//
//  Created by VASANTH K on 08/01/14.
//  
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WPCustomPickerView : UIDatePicker

@end
```

implementation file

```
//
//  WPCustomPickerView.m
//  test
//
//  Created by VASANTH K on 08/01/14.
//  
//

#import "WPCustomPickerView.h"

@implementation WPCustomPickerView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    id hitview=[super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
     if(!hitview)
     {
     if(point.y<=self.frame.size.height&&point.y>=0)
     return self;
      }
return hitview;
}


@end
```

Here i override the `hitTest` to make `UIPickerView`  response for the user interaction. This is the way how apple make main picker view transparent for user touch by return nil when user directly touch on the main view instead of picker content.